# Reducing quantity in text file list

Tags: python

how do I select an item from a specific text file .
and then the quantity of the item is reduced and the text file is updated .

I have tried this code.

```
def listingproductsbought(self):
    txtfile=open('user.txt','r')
```

the text file for example is:

```
--------------------------------
|ItemID|itemName|Quantity|Price|
|------|--------|--------|-----|
|P1    |Dior    |441     |24   |
|------|--------|--------|-----|
|P2    |Elie    |411     |30   |
|------|--------|--------|-----|
|P3    |Gucci   |415     |41   |
|------|--------|--------|-----|
|P4    |Armani  |310     |20   |
|------|--------|--------|-----|
|P5    |Hermes  |805     |23   |
|------|--------|--------|-----|
|P6    |Hugo    |300     |32   |
|------|--------|--------|-----|
|P7    |Givenchy|490     |51   |
|------|--------|--------|-----|
|P8    |Byredo  |900     |13   |
|------|--------|--------|-----|
|P9    |Bvlgari |550     |42   |
|------|--------|--------|-----|
|P10   |Versace |649     |43   |
--------------------------------
```

I want to select a product and when I do the item quantity(amount) will reduce.

The original content of the file looks like this (according to the original poster of the question):

```
ItemID itemName Quantity Price 
P1 Dior 441 24 
P2 Elie 411 30 
P3 Gucci 415 41 
P4 Armani 310 20 
P5 Hermes 805 23 
P6 Hugo 300 32 
P7 Givenchy 490 51 
P8 Byredo 900 13 
P9 Bvlgari 550 42 
P10 Versace 649 43
```

Comment: what do you mean quantity? What "items" are there in the text file?

Comment: the amount of items available for example their are 23 available perfumes in the shop to buy

Comment: copy and paste a sample of the text here. Mention what exactly you want "reduced" from it.

Comment: ItemID    itemName     Quantity         Price
P1 Dior 441 24
P2 Elie 411 30
P3 Gucci 415 41
P4 Armani 310 20
P5 Hermes 805 23
P6 Hugo 300 32
P7 Givenchy 490 51
P8 Byredo 900 13
P9 Bvlgari 550 42
P10 Versace 649 43.

Comment: this for example I want to select a product to buy and reduct the amount from the text file

Comment: text files is not suited for your task. You can use csv file

Comment: @user14517676--stack overflow highly recommends clarification text be added to the question rather than comments.

Comment: You can do that with plain python code, but I would rather recommend to consider pandas or to use a database. E.g. sqlite would be a lightweight database solution. That is not necessary, but why would you want to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Using plain Python code (i.e. no external libraries)

**Code**

```
def decrement_item(item_id, quantity):
    '''
        Decrement Quantity field based upon item_id
    
        inventory - file
        item_id   - item id to update
        quantity  - quantity to reduce by
    '''
    with open(inventory, 'r') as fin:
        # indexes for id and quantity
        index_id = 0
        index_quantity = 2
        
        # output buffer
        output = []
        
        # Add headaer to output buffer
        header = fin.readline().rstrip()
        output.append(header)  # header without '\n' at end of line
        
        bfound_item = False
        for line in fin:
            # Check each line for item_id then upadte quantity
            line = line.rstrip()
            if not bfound_item:
                # Only process if item_id has not been found yet
                # Break line into separate fields
                row = line.split()
                current_id = row[index_id]
                if current_id == item_id:
                    # Found item
                    # Check if sufficiente quantity
                    current_quantity = int(row[index_quantity])
                    if current_quantity >= quantity:
                        # Decrement quantity
                        current_quantity -= quantity
                        row[index_quantity] = str(current_quantity)
                        line = ' '.join(row)
                        bfound_item = True
                    else:
                        # Insufficient quantity for update
                        s = f"Sorry, available quantity is only {int(row[index_quantity])}"
                        raise Exception(s)
                    
            # Add line to output
            output.append(line)  # add copy since row changes with loop
            
    # Update inventory file
    with open(inventory, 'w') as fout:
        for line in output:
            fout.write(line + '\n')
```

**Test**

Keep decrementing amount in p4 by 100 until insufficient amount

```
while True:
    try:
        # keep updating quantity in P4 for
        # file inventory.txt until insufficient
        # amount remaining
        decrement_item("inventory.txt", "P4", 100)  # reduce P4 by 100
        
        # show updated inventory
        with open('inventory.txt', 'r') as fin:
            print('Contents of file inventory.txt')
            print(fin.read())
            
    except Exception as e:
        # Could not update
        print(e)
        break # Error during update
```

*Output of Test*

```
Contents of file inventory.txt
itemID itemName Quantity Price
P1 Dior 441 24
P2 Elie 411 30
P3 Gucci 415 41
P4 Armani 210 20
P5 Hermes 805 23
P6 Hugo 300 32
P7 Givenchy 490 51
P8 Byredo 900 13
P9 Bvlgari 550 42
P10 Versace 649 43

Contents of file inventory.txt
itemID itemName Quantity Price
P1 Dior 441 24
P2 Elie 411 30
P3 Gucci 415 41
P4 Armani 110 20
P5 Hermes 805 23
P6 Hugo 300 32
P7 Givenchy 490 51
P8 Byredo 900 13
P9 Bvlgari 550 42
P10 Versace 649 43

Contents of file inventory.txt
itemID itemName Quantity Price
P1 Dior 441 24
P2 Elie 411 30
P3 Gucci 415 41
P4 Armani 10 20
P5 Hermes 805 23
P6 Hugo 300 32
P7 Givenchy 490 51
P8 Byredo 900 13
P9 Bvlgari 550 42
P10 Versace 649 43

Sorry, available quantity is only 10
```